# How to configure bucket in admin-bro for local storage of uploaded files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using `express` with `admin-bro` and its plugin `@admin-bro/upload` to store uploaded image file in server.

The `AdminBro` object is initialized with the following `AdminBroOptions`

```js
const adminBro = new AdminBro({
        resources: [
            {
                resource: Furniture,
                options: {
                    properties: {
                        '_id': {
                            isVisible: { list: false, filter: true, show: true, edit: false }
                        },
                        image: {
                            isVisible: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                features: [uploadFeature({
                    provider: { local: { bucket: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'images', 'furniture') } },
                    properties: {
                        key: 'image.path',
                        bucket: 'image.folder',
                        mimeType: 'image.type',
                        size: 'image.size',
                        filename: 'image.filename',
                        file: 'uploadFile'
                    }
                })]
            }
        ],
        branding: {
            companyName: "Fran's Furniture"
        }
    })
```

The folder structure:

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnbr8.png)

I followed this tutorial mostly for `admin-bro` configuration: https://itnext.io/the-easiest-and-fastest-way-to-upload-files-in-node-js-4b49e0123190

I have also added `app.use('/public', express.static('public'))` in server.js file

But I run into this error while uploading image file:

```
(node:153012) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'F:'
```

If I change the bucket property to just 'public':

```js
provider: { local: { bucket: 'public' } }
```

The following error pops up (notice the 'public' folder is in F:/ not F:/path-to-project-folder:

```
(node:163580) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Error: EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\upload_4ca3c78a0517022a555815196102aee6' -> 'F:\public\5f98496b31e9d37efe9a2584\1.jpg'
```

The furniture model (if needed):

```js
const Image  = new mongoose.Schema({
    path: String,
    type: String,
    size: Number,
    folder: String,
    filename: String
})


const FurnitureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['show', 'hide'],
        default: 'show',
        required: true
    },
    condition: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['new', 'used'],
        required: true
    },
    image: Image,
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Category'
    }
})
```

So in my guess, the issue is mostly because of incorrect configuration of bucket option. Any help would be appreciated.

The project path (if needed): F:\Tutorials\Self-Projects\frans-node

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by writing a custom base provider myself and copying+removing the file manually:

```js
import { BaseProvider } from '@admin-bro/upload'
import { ActionContext, UploadedFile } from 'admin-bro'
import { promises, existsSync } from "fs"
import { resolve, dirname } from "path"

export class UploadProvider extends BaseProvider {
    assetPath: string
    constructor(bucket: string, assetPath: string) {
        // it requires bucket as a parameter to properly pass it to other methods
        super(bucket)

        this.assetPath = assetPath
    }

    async upload(file: UploadedFile, key: string, context: ActionContext): Promise<any> {
        const fullPath = resolve(this.assetPath, key)
        const dirPath = dirname(fullPath)

        if (!existsSync(dirPath)) {
            await promises.mkdir(dirPath, { recursive: true })
        }
        await promises.copyFile(file.path, fullPath)
        await promises.unlink(file.path)
        return key
    }

    async delete(key: string, bucket: string, context: ActionContext): Promise<any> {
        const filePath = resolve(this.assetPath, key)

        if (existsSync(filePath)) {
            await promises.unlink(filePath)
            const dirPath = dirname(filePath)
            const otherFiles = await promises.readdir(dirPath)
            if (otherFiles && otherFiles.length == 0) {
                await promises.rmdir(dirPath)
            }
        }
    }

    path(key: string, bucket: string, context: ActionContext): Promise<string> | string {
        return "/" + bucket
    }
}
```

And then, using it like:

```js
// ...
const provider = new UploadProvider("assets", ASSET_PATH)

// ...
features: [
    uploadFileFeature({ provider, ... })
]
```